# Use of an adjective instead of adverb with gerund?

Tags: adjectives, adverbs, gerunds, ing

I keep hearing on the BBC channel their self-commercial that goes like "We are the leaders in global breaking news".
Folks, could anybody kindly explain to me how come that structure is grammatically possible? My layman's understanding is that if gerund is used as a verb, "breaking" (breaking WHAT? breaking news) then only an adverb can be used to characterize the action. That is "breaking news globally", unless "breaking" is meant as as an adjective describing news, which doesn't seem to make any sense.
Thanks for any comments.

Comment: I'd be inclined to say that the semantic divergence from the verb "breaking" is sufficient to establish that this "breaking" is an adjective, not a verb. Contrast the NP  "sleeping chid", where "sleeping" is a verb phrase, not an adjective. "Global" modifies the nominal "breaking news".

Answer (score 1):

The term 'breaking news' is a fixed expression as defined in [this Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/breaking_news):

> [mass noun]
>
> Newly received information about an event that is currently occurring or developing.
>
> ‘some breaking news now of a rescue situation in California’
>
> ‘the announcement will likely be the lead story for the broadcast, barring other major breaking news’

So 'breaking' here isn't a verb that takes 'news' as object.

The best way to learn these things is by simply getting used to these fixed expressions.

Technically, 'breaking' *can* be a verb that takes 'news' as object, but these are normally limited to 'the news' as in:

> I hate to break the news to you, but you're wrong.
>
> BBC was the first to break the news.

But this sounds unidiomatic if not ungrammatical:

> We are the leaders in breaking news globally.

### EDIT

I need to clarify my position about whether *breaking* in *breaking news* is a verb or an adjective.

When I said:

> 'breaking' here isn't a verb that takes 'news' as object

I didn't mean that *breaking* in *breaking news* is not a verb but an adjective, although OED cited in the other answer disagrees. What I meant was only that it is not a verb that takes 'news' as object. But it still *is* a verb (and not yet an adjective), a verb that doesn't take 'news' as object, i.e., an intransitive verb.

According to *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (page 541), *sleeping* in *a sleeping child* is not an adjective but a verb, and this is what the book says about the criterion for determining whether a participle in a pre-modifying construction is a verb or an adjective:

> In general, we will take the form as a verb if it cannot function as a predicative adjective. We have already seen that *sleeping* has no predicative adjective use; cf. also *a smiling face*, *the sinking ship*, *a dying man*, etc.

That is, if a participle in a pre-modifying construction cannot function as a predicative adjective, the participle is a verb.

> *The child is sleeping.*
>
> *The face is smiling.*
>
> *The ship is sinking.*
>
> *The man is dying.*

In none of the above examples can the participle function as a predicative adjective; it can only function as a verb embedded in the progressive construction.

Now turning to the current example:

> *The news is breaking.*

Here, *breaking* cannot function as a predicative adjective, either. Therefore, *breaking* in *breaking news* (as well as in *late-breaking news*) *is* a verb, despite OED's classification otherwise.

Comment: Perfect, case closed. Thanks JK2. That is the key link to the Oxford Dictionary entry for the mass compound noun "breaking news" - that fact I just didn't know. It totally explains and grammatically legitimizes the use of adjective. Nothing to add here.

Comment: @Phil Merriam-Webster also defines the noun [*late-breaking news*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/breaking%20news).

Comment: @JasonBassford I think 'late' there is an adverb that modifies the verb 'break'. And this use shows that 'breaking' does have some aspect of a verb, albeit limited.

Comment: @jk2 No, the entire phrase is a noun. That's why the dictionary *defines* it as a noun. (But you can disagree with the dictionary if you like. Although I don't know why you'd want to argue against your own answer . . .)

Comment: @JasonBassford Maybe I'm misunderstanding what you're saying, but why would I want to argue against my own answer? 'Cause I'm not. Just because 'late' is an adverb doesn't mean 'late-breaking news' is not an NP. (The entire phrase 'late-breaking news' is not a noun but a noun phrase, which are two different things.) For example, _the recently announced news_ is an NP but includes an adverb _recently_.

Comment: @JK2 Right. Except that by saying that *late-breaking news* from Merriam-Webster is not a compound noun along the same lines as just *breaking news* from Oxford, you *are* arguing against your answer. The word in Merriam-Webster is not a noun phrase. It's an actual noun. Exactly in the same way that *ice cream* is a compound noun. Or [*dead-cat bounce*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dead-cat%20bounce) is a noun. I said that the phrase is a noun—but it actually isn't a phrase that's acting as a noun in a one-off construction. It *is* a noun—at least according to Merriam-Webster.

Comment: Which is why we can have *global (**breaking news**)* and *global (**late-breaking news**)*, and *global* remains an adjective that is applied against a compound noun in both cases.

Comment: @JasonBassford As far as I know, a compound noun can always be an NP, although the other way around is not true. In _I love ice cream_, the compound noun _ice cream_ is an NP functioning as object of the verb _love_. Since _ice cream_ is a compound noun, it cannot be coordinated like this: *_ice and chocolate creams_. But such a coordination is entirely possible with _breaking news_ as in: _breaking and developing news_. So I believe that _breaking news_ can be an NP but is not a compound noun.

Comment: @JasonBassford That being said, I don't know why me saying _(late-)breaking news_ is not a compound noun, which is true, has anything to do with me arguing against my own answer.

Comment: I can't believe that I agree with your answer, but completely disagree with your comments. I'm amazed that you would use one dictionary definition to support your claim—but deny the equivalent entry in a different dictionary. When you say *breaking and developing news* you are ***not*** using the noun *breaking news*. You are using different words. If you split a dictionary word into separate components, you are no longer using the word.

Comment: @JasonBassford No, I'm not using "different words". In case you didn't know, that's a legitimate test for a compound noun.

Comment: @JK2 A *compound noun* is any group of words that have been used often enough in conjunction *as a noun* (to which other syntactic units can be applied, as with any other noun), such that it is treated as a single, indivisible unit by a majority of language users—as indicated by its presence in major dictionaries. The individual words *in* a compound can be prised apart and treated as individual words, but they are not *the same* word. Your objection here is undermining your answer. (Or else you quoted a dictionary definition you don't really believe in.)

Comment: @JasonBassford That's your personal opinion. Just because 'breaking news' is shown as a noun in a dictionary, major or not, doesn't mean the dictionary treats it a compound noun. And even if it does, dictionaries in general are a very unreliable source for determining parts of speech, let alone determining whether it's a compound noun. Like I said, the coordination test is what linguists normally do to determine whether a 'adjective/noun + noun' combination is a compound noun or not. The very existence of _breaking and developing news_ proves that _breaking news_ is not a compound noun.

Comment: @JasonBassford Upon re-reading the comments, I think I can figure out what you mean. When I said "_breaking_ does have some aspect of a verb, albeit limited", I was referring to _late-breaking news_, not _breaking news_. My answer to the question here applies only to the latter. And the former can be treated differently because it has another element, namely, _late-_.

Comment: @JasonBassford I've added 'edit' to my answer to clarify my position on the matter. I stand corrected about my last comment.

Comment: I don't understand the purported problem with recasting the attributively used *sleeping child* as a predicate adjective by saying *the child is sleeping*. How does that fail? Seems sound to me. A failing predicate test is more normally used to show that something is a noun not an adjective. For example, the failure of *sleeping bag* to transform into *the bag is sleeping* without a drastic change in meaning shows that there it is a noun, not an adjective.

Comment: @tchrist Two better verbs for testing words that might be adjectives are _become_ and _seem_. _Sleeping_ fails these: *_The child seemed sleeping_ *_The child became sleeping_

Answer (score 0):

The Oxford English Dictionary certainly recognizes the use of *breaking* as an adjective with the most recent (2016) revision to the entry for breaking explaining, specifically, that when used in relation to a news story, the adjective  refers to a story that is currently developing or is recent.

Interestingly, the earliest recorded example is from 1877 in an *American* newspaper.

Comment: The on-line Oxford doesn't list it, and that's probably the dictionary that most people around here use. But I agree that's it adjective solely on the grounds of its semantic divergence from the verb form "breaking". In all other respects it has the properties of a verb.

Comment: Dictionaries, even OED, are a very unreliable source for parts-of-speech classification.